# Как сделать поиск по каждому столбцу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть таблица с поиском по каждому столбцу и общий поиск.

Почему не работает скрипт поиска?
Вроде все логично оформил

Каждый **input** сохраняется в **state**, чтобы следующий **input** искал по уже найденным результатам.
Почему-то не работает данный скрипт

Песочница [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-oskar-wkkrr?file=/src/App.js)
**state.data** - массив для вывода на страницу 
**state.json** - получаемый массив с сервера
**state.search** - объект с input для поиска

```
dataHave.map(item => { // перебор массива объектов, где ищем слова
      for (let key in searchHave) {  // перебор каждого input для поиска
        JSON.stringify(item) // объект из массива для поиска превращаем в строку
          .toUpperCase()
          .indexOf(searchHave[key].toUpperCase()) > -1 // поиск каждого input
          ? filteredData.push(item) // если вхождения найдены - сохраняем элемент в новый массив 
          : false;
      }
    });
```

Чувствую, запутался сильно, буду благодарен за любой ответ, хотя бы направление куда двигаться.

Answer (score 0):

Обрати внимание что
item = {
          number: 1,
          name: "John",
          surname: "Doe",
          job: "Designer"
        },
И тогда что у тебя получится тут:

```
JSON.stringify(item) // объект для поиска превращаем в строку
```